# Why does SQL Server require INT to be converted to NVARCHAR?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, character-encoding

During an ordeal yesterday, I learned that you can't pass this query to EXEC():

```
@SQL = @SQL + 'WHERE ID = ' + @SomeID
EXCEC(@SQL)
```

Where @SomeID is an INT and @SQL is NVARCHAR. This will complain about not being able to convert NVARCHAR back to INT during execution.

I realized you have to do it like

```
@SQL = @SQL + 'WHERE ID = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), @SomeID)
```

What I didn't understand is why? Why doesn't SQL Server understand the INT when simply +:ed on to an NVARCHAR? I'm guessing it has something to do with char sets.

EDIT: Fixed typos (missed some +:s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**+ (String Concatenation)**

> An operator in a string expression
>   that concatenates two or more
>   character or binary strings, columns,
>   or a combination of strings and column
>   names into one expression (a string
>   operator).
>
> Expression is any valid Microsoft® SQL Server™
>   expression of any of the data types in
>   the character and binary data type
>   category, except the image, ntext, or
>   text data types. Both expressions must
>   be of the same data type, **or one
>   expression must be able to be
>   implicitly converted to the data type
>   of the other expression.**

So... There is no implicit convertion of int to string... This is an internal question

Comment: The next question would of course be why there is no implicit convertion of int to string, but I guess I'll just have to live with it.

Comment: I guess it is not allowed because it is too prone to error(there is a chance to loose data (if the nvarchar field is too short ot something...), the same way you can't cast int to bool in C#

Comment: But implicit conversion of an INT to NVARCHAR is allowed as is implicit conversion of NVARCHAR to INT. See chart on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054(SQL.80).aspx. However, when seeing a + operator with a number on one and a char/nchar/varchar/nvarchar on the other side, SQL Server attempts the implicit conversion to the numeric type and then doing an add instead of converting the numeric to a string and concatinating. It is ambigous what is wanted. MS (and probably Sybase before them) chose one way. If you want the other, you have to use explicit conversion.

Comment: To see implicit conversion of an INT to NVARCHAR, create a stored proc that takes an NVARCHAR and then call with an int. It will work, without explicit casting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying this will definitely work, and I'm not near my sql management studio to try it before posting, but have you tried something like this:

```
@SQL = @SQL + 'Where ID = ' + @SomeID
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Ach! That's a typo. My bad. + one for spotting, and correcting without mocking me. ;)